# How to turn pandas.groupby.agg and pandas.resample on minutes into SQL queries?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I's like to run the following Pandas (Python) queries in SQL but no clue how to do:

```
df.resample("Min", on="timestamp").col1.sum() / df.resample("Min", on="timestamp").col2.sum()

df.groupby("col1").agg(new_col_1 = ("col_2","mean"), new_col_1 = ("col_3", lambda x: x.count() / len(x)))
```

Comment: I think the best is add some sample data and expected ouput, sql expert obviously not working with pandas.

Comment: In addition to sample data and desired results, you should include a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: There is no sample data neither database, only table schemas from an otherwise unseen dbase.